# Oracle: find place in code where update was called

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

The problem is: my procedure updates value in specific column and few miliseconds later this value is null. I try to find place where value from specific column is being changed to null.

Is it possible to check which procedure/trigger calls update on the column in Oracle DB?

Comment: `column in my table is cleaned` what does this mean ? What are you trying to achieve

Comment: @xing I didnt make myself clear. It just means that value in this column is being changed to null.

Comment: You could look at all_dependencies to see all packages/procedures/triggers dependant on that table; and then manually review.  you could interrogate ALL_SOURCE for all code containing the table in question or something like 'fieldname = NULL'  However these approaches assume the offending code is in the database.  (both of these assume you have permissions necessary to view the detail of all objects.

Comment: If i understood you correctly you need to check if the column is updated or not. You can use a triiger for that as show below. Am not assuming that it would be NULL. You can set that condition in the trigger.

Comment: Do you have a test case you can run from your IDE (SQL Developer, PL/SQL Developer etc)? If so I would just step through it in the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_call_stack);
```

You can put this code in trigger or in procedure/function code where you think your field is changing a value.

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a trigger as below if i understood you correctly. Here I am checking if the new value of the column of your table is different than old value, then display the message that `Updat occured on Column` . You can extend the checking condition on all the columns of your table in `when` clause of trigger shown below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER chk
 BEFORE INSERT ON Your_Table
 FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (
new.col1 <> old.col1
OR new.col1 is NULL
      )
 begin      
   dbms_output.put_line('Updat occured on Column');
  end;
/
```

Comment: This solution is fine when I would like to see a moment of update. But I want to print additionally a name of procedure/trigger which fires an update. My problem: my procedure updates value in specific column and few miliseconds later this value is null.

Comment: You can check `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` to find out which all pkgs and procedures are using the table but it would be difficult to tell which one actually invoked that update at that particular time until you have `AWR` report with you.

Comment: Thank you for the last comment, it might be helpful.

Comment: You could make the `WHEN` clause more specific to cut down on inappropriate firings of your trigger.  For example, if `COL1` is null, this trigger will fire when any other column in the database is updated.  Also, see Andrey Khmelev's answer for a far more useful `DBMS_OUTPUT` than what you've got so far.